# How to best store a one key and billion values kind of data?

Tags: database, algorithm, database-design, store, key-value

I have a requirement where I want to store the key-value kind of data but one key could have billion of values. There are mostly the read requests by key but there could be add/delete requests for some values out of all the values for a given key. Order of the values doesn't matter.

Read requests needs to be faster in comparison to the add/delete requests.

Comment: How will they be requested? By key? What do you want to do with the value data? Just return it?

Comment: Yes by key. I have modified the question too.

Comment: How about a single table where the primary key is the combination of key and value?

Comment: @ripudam .. my bad .. didnt see the tags .. you wanted a database implementation is it ..  I deleted my answer to avoid confusion

Comment: It's a little odd to have that many values tied to the same key. The corollary is that when you request a key, you get __all__ of these values. What do you do with billion values all at once? Load them all into memory and process them somehow? Stream them somewhere else? Isn't there a way to identify some subset of these values that you actually need?

Comment: I think you can choose between [Key-value stores](http://db-engines.com/en/article/Key-value+Stores) and [Time series DBMS](http://db-engines.com/en/article/Time+Series+DBMS).
Looks like they are suitable for you problem domain.

Comment: @Branko Dimitrijevic Does it really matter for what reason do I need the values? Also, whether we need it at once or load page by page or chunk by chunk shouldn't affect the storage solution? However, there is no way to create the subset of values.

Comment: @ripudam The reason matters if it reveals a way to avoid fetching billion rows. But if you are adamant it cannot be done differently, then you cannot expect "close to real-time" performance for fetching billion rows, no matter how good your storage solution is.

Comment: @Branko Dimitrijevic I might have miscommunicated a bit. What I actually meant is read request are more frequent and need to faster in comparison to add/delete requests. Since there will be billion values, we will have to fetch them using page by page. As long as we are able to find all the values for a key, fetching is not problematic.